Can I still use Apache Camel with Spring Boot versions greater than 3.3.x

Why is spring initializer not allowing me to add apache camel as spring boot starter for version 3.3.3 ?
I tried to find information on this removal but can't find any in documentation.
For now i found documentation on how to integrate camel with spring boot https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/4.8.x/spring-boot.html and will follow that but i was curious on why its still now awailable from initializer ?
